# Is there any performance / compile time benefits with importing UIKit instead of specific UIKit component?

Tags: ios, objective-c, import, frameworks

For example I have following interface.

```
#import<UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface someClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *string;
@property (nonatomic, copy) UIFont *font;
@end
```

I feel like we are unnecessarily importing whole UIKit. I'm not sure if following will be better than above or not.

```
#import<Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import<UIKit/UIFont.h>

@interface someClass: NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *string;
@property (nonatomic, copy) UIFont *font;
@end
```

I think with importing only UIKit I can get around of not requiring to list all other needed frameworks. But is there any real advantage / disadvantage of doing so ? Also if instead of using #import, I used @import modules will that make any difference in this particular example.

Answer (score 3):

In theory, yes. This is how C and then Objective-C headers were designed. You're supposed to only import the components you need because that's less work for the compiler, hence faster compile times. If you look at Apple frameworks that's usually how they work (each header only imports components it uses).

In practice, this is going to be a huge amount of work for you to maintain the list of exactly the headers you need, and you're going to see almost no performance improvements. That's because UIKit components are very tied together, meaning your `UIFont.h` header is going to import other UIKit headers which in turn import other headers, etc... And you end up importing most of UIKit every time anyway.

What really makes a difference, as you mention, is a compiler feature called [Modules](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html) which needs to be enabled (but I believe it is enabled by default, check `Enable modules` in Xcode build settings). When you use modules, for example the UIKit module, the compiler compiles the whole module once the first time it is imported and then caches it. Then all other imports of the same module in your source files will use this cached version which result in much faster compile times.

By default you would import the UIKit module by doing `@import UIKit;`, but the compiler will also understand `#import<UIKit/UIKit.h>` as an import of the UIKit module (if modules are enabled), so it will work the same way.

You can also import part of a module using dot notation (e.g. `@import UIKit.UIFont;`), but keep in mind that this will still trigger a compilation and caching of the whole module, so don't see it as a performance improvement. Again, the compiler will understand `#import<UIKit/UIFont.h>` as `@import UIKit.UIFont;`.

With all of that said, the answer to your question is : `#import<UIKit/UIKit.h>` and `#import<UIKit/UIFont.h>` will result in the exact same performance impact. And you should use the first one because it's much easier, thank the compiler authors, and never think about it again!